# Plot x and y coordinates on an image using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I want to plot x and y coordinates on an image by drawing a circle around the point. 
I am getting the image from the server as an array buffer. After the image is displayed i need to mark the corners in the image using coordinates sent as a json from a service.
How can i do this using javascript jquery?
I was thinking of doing the same by overlaying the image with a canvas layer.
How can i implement this?

I have tried the below method but the points were getting plotted outside the image

```
jQuery('#plotCoordinates').on('click',function(){


        jQuery.getJSON( "plot.json", function( response ) {
            console.log("response >> " ,response);
            var imageCanvas = $('#imageCan');


            jQuery.each(response,function(i,obj){
                console.log('obj >> ',obj);
                point = $('<div class="plot-point"></div>');
                x = obj.x,
                        y = obj.y;

                point.css({
                    left: x + "px",
                    top: y + "px"
                });
                point.appendTo(imageCanvas);
            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: have you tried anything yet ? you mentioned canvas : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API

Answer (score 2):

You can certainly do it using a canvas.Do the following steps-->

1. Draw image on canvas as image size=canvas size.
2. Now, overlay another canvas with a higher z-index exactly on the previous canvas(canvas is transparent by default).
3. Now use the coordinates of the points you fetched using json to mark the     corners in the image by plotting them on this overlayed canvas.
4. Then you can draw circles around these points on the upper canvas using simple context functions.

As canvas size is same as image size these coordinates will exactly coincide and you can achieve want you want :).In short you draw your circles and markings on the upper canvas and simply draw image on the lower canvas.Easy huhh??:)

Note:Both the canvases and the image itself should be of equal dimensions to exactly coincide.

Have a look at this example https://jsfiddle.net/rbrv949d/

```
<canvas id="c"  style="z-index: 1;"></canvas>
<canvas id="cover" style="z-index: 2;"></canvas>
```

JS onload

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('c');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var canover=document.getElementById('cover');

var ctxover = canvas.getContext('2d');

// Create an image element
var img = new Image();

// When the image is loaded, draw it
img.onload = function () {
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    ctxover.fillRect(0,0,10,10);
     ctxover.fillRect(0,20,10,10);
}

// Specify the src to load the image
img.src = "http://www.experts-exchange.com/images/experts-exchange/experts-exchange-logo.png";

canvas.width=img.width;
canvas.height=img.height;


canover.width=img.width;
canover.height=img.height;
```

Here , ctxover.fillRect(xposition,yposition,widthinpixels,heightinpixels)
In your case,the xposition and yposition are the one fetched from json.
You can also draw those markings on the same canvas without using the overlayed canvas.Its upto you.Provided if you clear this canvas those markings will also get cleared unlike the other case :)

Comment: But i am getting stuck at the point where i have to plot the coordinates. How do i do it? I was able to achieve step 1. I haven't worked with canvas so this is new to me .